Issue with Integrating FloatingPanel and Map Interaction in SwiftUI App
I am currently using FloatingPanel version 2.8.6 to develop an iOS application .The app uses SwiftUI as the main framework, but I am integrating FloatingPanel using UIKit as a wrapped UIViewController.
However, I have been facing an issue with integrating FloatingPanel over a MapView (implemented using SwiftUI's Map). When FloatingPanel is displayed, the interaction with the map, such as panning or zooming, becomes disabled, even though the FloatingPanel is not covering the whole screen. Here is a summary of the setup:
App Overview:
MapView: SwiftUI's Map view, always displayed in the background.
FloatingPanel: Implemented using UIKit, and wrapped in a UIViewControllerRepresentable for SwiftUI compatibility.
MenuBar: A TabView or custom menu bar at the bottom of the screen, which allows users to switch between different panels.
Specific Issue:
When FloatingPanel is added to the view hierarchy, the MapView in the background becomes unresponsive.
Removing the FloatingPanel component allows the Map to function normally again.
Here is a simplified version of my current implementation:
FloatingPanelHostController.swift:
import UIKit
import FloatingPanel

class FloatingPanelHostController: UIViewController, FloatingPanelControllerDelegate {
var fpc: FloatingPanelController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        fpc = FloatingPanelController(delegate: self)
        fpc.layout = MyFloatingPanelLayout()  // Custom layout for FloatingPanel
    
        let contentVC = UIViewController()
        contentVC.view.backgroundColor = .white
        fpc.set(contentViewController: contentVC)
    
        fpc.addPanel(toParent: self, animated: true)
    }

}

class MyFloatingPanelLayout: FloatingPanelLayout {
let position: FloatingPanelPosition = .bottom
let initialState: FloatingPanelState = .tip
let anchors: \[FloatingPanelState: FloatingPanelLayoutAnchoring\] = \[
.full: FloatingPanelLayoutAnchor(absoluteInset: 16.0, edge: .top, referenceGuide: .safeArea),
.half: FloatingPanelLayoutAnchor(fractionalInset: 0.5, edge: .bottom, referenceGuide: .safeArea),
.tip: FloatingPanelLayoutAnchor(absoluteInset: 44.0, edge: .bottom, referenceGuide: .safeArea),
\]
}\`

MainView.swift:
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct MainView: View {
@State private var selectedTab = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MapView()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    
            FloatingPanelWrapper()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                MenuBarView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                    .frame(height: 50)
            }
        }
    }

}

struct FloatingPanelWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -\> FloatingPanelHostController {
let controller = FloatingPanelHostController()
return controller
}

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: FloatingPanelHostController, context: Context) {
    }

}

Could you please provide any suggestions on how to resolve the issue of map interaction while using FloatingPanel? Specifically:
Is there a way to make the MapView interactable when FloatingPanel is present?
Should I change the FloatingPanel configuration, such as backdrop settings or layout, to allow user interactions in the background?
If this is a known limitation, is there any recommended workaround?

FloatingPanel Integration with SwiftUI:


Integrated FloatingPanel with SwiftUI by wrapping it in UIViewControllerRepresentable to make it compatible with SwiftUI views.
Added the FloatingPanel as a child view controller within the FloatingPanelHostController and used a custom layout (MyFloatingPanelLayout) to control the panel's position and state (full, half, tip).
FloatingPanel Layout Adjustments:

